# How to modify this function to use structs as arguments rather than doubles

Tags: c

```
/* the struct */
typedef struct atom {
    double x;
    double y;
    double z;
    char line[200];
    int is_connected;
    struct atom *next;
} p_atom;

/* the existing function */  
double
calcdist (double px, double py, double pz, double lx, double ly, double lz )   
{  
    double x, y, z, sqr_sum;
    x = px - lx;
    y = py - ly;
    z = pz - lz;
    sqr_sum = pow (x, 2) + pow (y, 2) + pow (z, 2);
    return sqrt (sqr_sum);
}
```

1. The above program is written to calculate distance between 2 points
   in 3D. If I want to write a new function that accepts x,y,z
   coordinates via my struct and calculates distance (same as above), is it
   possible...if so how?
2. How do I execute a c program giving multiple input files on the command line.

Comment: If the program has multiple source files, you would compile them with a command like `gcc aaa.c bbb.c  -o myprog` and then execute the program with `./myprog`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**the elegant**:

```
typedef struct {
    double          x;
    double          y;
    double          z;
}COORD_3D;



typedef struct atom {
    COORD_3D        coord;
    char            line[200];
    int             is_connected;
    struct atom     *next;
} p_atom;



double calc3Ddist (COORD_3D *coord1, COORD_3D *coord2)   
{  
    double x, y, z, sqr_sum;
    x = coord1->x - coord2->x;
    y = coord1->y - coord2->y;
    z = coord1->z - coord2->z;

    sqr_sum = pow (x, 2) + pow (y, 2) + pow (z, 2);
    return sqrt (sqr_sum);
}


int HowToDo(){

    p_atom      a, b;
    int         dist;

    dist=calcdist( &a.coord, &b.coord);

}
```

Comment: In both cases the code is fine, but as commented by many, and many times, you need to provide an explanation of what your code does and how it responds to the question. When you are answering, you step into the shoes of the teacher. That requires some explanation of, for instance, why you pass a pointer to struct as a parameter instead of an instance, etc.. I'm not picking on you, I'm really just trying to help improve the quality and completeness of your answers. They could be quite good with a bit more effort.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, thank you. but that is my weekness (commenting in fluent english).

Comment: Thank you so much sir. You made my day.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps the first thing to do is to read a C book, especially on how a function works.. I'll give you some hints anyway.

> 1. If i want to write a subroutine that accepts x,y,z coordinates and calculates distance (same as above), is it possible...if so how?

It is possible, and actually the good way to do it. You can pass as many parameters to function as you want. In this case, however, it's probably better to pass pointer to `struct`. That way is usually more convenient and more efficient than passing several parameters.

```
double calcdist( p_atom *point1, p_atom *point2 )
```

Inside that function, you can do the calculation with `point1->x`, `point1->y`, etc. as you currently do with your `px`, `py`, etc.

> 2. How to execute a c program by giving multiple input files in command line

You can `cat` multiple input files and then `pipe` them to your program. Something like:

```
cat file1 file2 | ./a.out
```

Comment: I think (2) above was asking a bit more about utilizing the `argc` and `argv` arguments to `main()`. That would also be covered in your suggestion of a *C book* though.

Comment: if you move the second question to a new thread (post) , you will get more detailed and useful answers . avoid to ask many questions in same post. especially if they have different aspects.

Comment: Thank you sir. I will post it as another question

Answer (score -1):

**the simpler:**

```
double
calcdist (p_atom *patom, p_atom *latom )   
{  
    double x, y, z, sqr_sum;
    x = patom->x - latom->x;
    y = patom->y - latom->y;
    z = patom->z - latom->z;

    sqr_sum = pow (x, 2) + pow (y, 2) + pow (z, 2);
    return sqrt (sqr_sum);
}
```

Comment: You've been around for a bit now. Why do you keep posting several answers to a question? This does not anything useful anyway, so it may as well be purged altogether. If you feel like preserving it, [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34671249/edit) your other answer to this question.

Comment: @IInspectable, upon a time, i was the only who posted answers. two, answers is not too much.

Comment: Two answers, in general, are fine. Two answers **by the same author** is one too many. You already found out, [how to delete an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34696636/1889329). It's time you learnt, how to [edit an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34671249/edit) as well.